# PHP: Why is "${obj->prop}" a parsing error, while "$obj->prop" is legal?

Tags: php, parsing, string-formatting

PHP 7.3.2

When parsing variables inside PHP’s double quoted strings, there is one parsing error that I find peculiar:

```php
echo "${obj->prop}"; // Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

// But this is legal:
echo "$obj->prop";

// And, for instance, all these are legal as well:
echo "${arr['key']}";
echo "${arr[0]}";
echo "${arr['0']}";
```

Why is the interpreter prejudiced specifically against `->` within `${…}`?

Comment: Maybe you want `${$obj->prop}`

Comment: The `$` goes before the variable and *inside* the braces.

Comment: I'm not sure why the last 3 are legal, it's probably for backward compatibility.

Comment: @Barmar I am aware of the complex variable parsing syntax and am not asking how to insert an object property into a string. Hell, I’m even including the working method for the latter in my question.

Comment: @AbraCadaver This is the syntax for parsing a dynamic variable name. I am asking about a reason for the specific parsing error.

Comment: But I get it, I think. PHP is an old rope, lots of loose ends. If even the last three examples aren’t expected to be legal, then the `${…}` syntax is probably intended for simple variable names only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, curly braces like that are not an alternate form of complex variable parsing syntax.

`"$var"` and `"${var}"` are simple syntax, and `"{$var}"` is complex syntax.

In simple syntax, the interpreter is strictly looking for a variable name, not an expression, and curly braces are used only used to indicate the end of the name, in case you have something like `"${var}othertext"`. The manual states

> If a dollar sign ($) is encountered, the parser will greedily take as many tokens as possible to form a valid variable name. Enclose the variable name in curly braces to explicitly specify the end of the name.

The interpreter is not prejudiced specifically against `->` within `${…}`, actually the interpreter is very strict about what it considers a valid variable name within `${…}` and makes one exception for accessing a single array key.

You can't do `"${var['a']['b']}"`, for example.

During the first step in interpreting the code, when the string is being tokenized, `${` is a token `T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES`, that sets the scanner to a "looking for variable name" state. In that state, the only thing that will be recognized as a variable name is a valid label followed by an open square bracket or the closing curly brace.

Tokenizing the array key example looks like this:

```
source: "           ${                      arr         [             'key'             ]  }  "
tokens: " T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES  T_STRING_VARNAME  [  T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING   ]  }  "
```

And the object property example looks like this:

```
source: "           ${                     obj            ->             prop    }  "
tokens: " T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES    T_STRING   T_OBJECT_OPERATOR   T_STRING  }  "
```

The parse error happens in the next step, where the object operator is applied to a string, where it is unexpected.

Using simple syntax without the curly braces, you get these tokens instead, which work just fine as you know:

```
source: "     $obj            ->            prop   "
tokens: "  T_VARIABLE  T_OBJECT_OPERATOR  T_STRING "
```

Comment: This is an exquisitely informative answer. I’m curious where you get your information about parser workings, but in any way, thank you.

Comment: You can use this to tokenize a string of php source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php, and look through this to get an idea of how the tokens are produced: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l